# Displayling a password generated in a function

Tags: php, function, passwords

I'm a PHP beginner and I'm doing a site who will require a login/logout page.
For more clarity I decided to put all that's relevant to the inscription on a function called addUser. My question is the following : The function takes in parameters the username and mail address, generates a random password, and stores on a file the array $user, who have the username, the mail address and a SHA1 hash of the password. The function returns true if all the process is good, and false if there's no username or mail address, or if a similar username exists.

My question is : How can I display the generated password safely when calling this function ?

Thank you, and sorry if my question is trivial, but I haven't found any solution yet.

addUser function :

```
function addUser($pseudo, $mail)
{
$pseudo = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $pseudo);
$required = array($pesudo, $mail); 
foreach ($required as $field){
    if (empty($_POST[$field])){
        return(false);
    }
}
else{
// put the existing username test.
$password = random_password();
echo $password;
$hash = sha1($password);
$user = array(
    "pseudo" => $pseudo,
    "mail" => $email,
    "hash" => $hash,
);
$user = serialize($user);
file_put_contents('db', $user."\n", FILE_APPEND);
return(true);
unset($password);
}
```

Comment: In general it is considered a bad approach to generate random passwords and hand them out for usage. An initial (random) password should never be used, so it does not have to be known. Offer a login token with limited lifetime for the initial login after an account has been generated. That token (or better a link carrying the token) can be sent in an email, that way you automatically have implemented the double opt-in required and expected today.

Comment: If you really want to generate a random password, then there isn't really any choice other than to display it to the user in plain text. There's no save vs. non-safe way, you just display it on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PLEASE adhere to the advise to NOT do this!  At the least, hash the user's password and store THAT hash.

As to what you're wanting to do, though, you could return FALSE on failure and the hash on success (that is, do not return TRUE).  When calling this function, check for FALSE and assume not-FALSE means "true"-ish.

Comment: Ok, it took me a long time but I, as all of you said, decided to go with user's defined passwords, and this function no longer exists.

Answer (score 0):

If a password is generated and displayed, then it is never truely safe. You might want to consider instead of assigning someone a password, you email them a unique key ID via email to then set their password.

Or reduce all functionality until a custom password is submitted on login.

And of course there's the "Why aren't you just allowing users to set their own password in the first place?"

Comment: I'm using randomly generated passwords because of my lack of skills. In a near future I will use user-set passwords, but now, randomly generated passwords are fine, with a limited lifetime for example ?

Comment: Well the answer to your question is "it's never going to be safe to display a generated password (or any password)".

Lack of skills? You're going to allow people to log in, there's essentially no difference in the process of cleaning the password for tags, encrypting it...

Also, storing user information in a file is not secure, and poor privacy management (users emails sit in a file that is not tokened and is easy to obtain)